# Java 7 new IO API - Paths.exists

Tags: java, api, nio

Does anyone know what happened to the `path.exists()` API method in the latest Java 7 API? 
I cannot find the change in the change logs, and between b123 and b130, the method has been removed from the API.I see that there is a static `Files.exists` method but I'm not sure if that is the replacement or not.

Is anyone following the Java 7 work close enough to know how this should be handled?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps in JDK8 it will be added back in as a defender method. :)

Comment: An alternative is to return a File object representing that path by calling toFile() and then calling *its* exists() method.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

## `Files.exists`

Look in the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class for the static methods [`exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) and [`notExists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-). Both take a [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

I guess they decided it made more sense as a [static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) rather than instance method.